# Getting 403 Error when sending an email with Laravel and Sparkpost

Tags: php, laravel, email, sparkpost

I get a 403 *Forbidden* response when attempting to send an email using Sparkpost from my Laravel 5.6 application. I added the Sparkpost api key to both the `.env` file and `services.php` file. Key is correct.

`.env` file:

```
enter code here
MAIL_DRIVER=sparkpost
SPARKPOST_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

`services.php` file:

```
'sparkpost' => [
        'secret' => env('xxxxxxxxxx'),
    ],
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Your question is not complete.It may be because of not set port of smtp,host of smtp,password of smtp or even do not disable less-secure or 2step setting of sender account or even using of Mail facade.offer complete code please

Comment: One likely cause for that 403 error is your API key does not include the permission for "Transmission". You can check that in SparkPost here https://app.sparkpost.com/account/api-keys